# random request timeouts - rails, postgres, passenger, nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, nginx, passenger

Have a rails API app, hosted on cloud with phusion passenger and nginx. Requests to the API are getting timed out if the API is not accessed for some time.

Checking the logs, it seems the requests successfully hits rails and this is where it times out.

Here is the rails log

```
PG::UnableToSend (server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.

activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:215:in `exec'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:215:in `dealloc'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:198:in `block in clear'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:197:in `each_value'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:197:in `clear'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:258:in `clear_cache!'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:291:in `reconnect!'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:275:in `reconnect!'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:328:in `verify!'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:456:in `block in checkout_and_verify'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_checkout_callbacks'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:455:in `checkout_and_verify'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
airbrake (5.2.3) lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

database.yml configuration

```
database: xxx
username: xxx
password: xxx
host: xxx
port: 5432
pool: 10
```

Passenger configuration

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name {{server_name}};
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env {{env}};
    root {{rails_app_root}}/{{rails_app_package_name}}-{{node_env}}/public;
    passenger_min_instances 3;
 }
 passenger_max_request_queue_size 500;
 passenger_pre_start http://{{server_name}}{{pre_start_url}};
 passenger_spawn_method direct;
 passenger_pool_idle_time 0;
 passenger_max_preloader_idle_time 0;
```

Any pointers on why this could be happening? 
This does not happen always, only if you access the service after it has been idle for sometime.

Comment: have you a host as remote?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ yes the db is on a remote machine. is that what you meant?

Comment: Is it possible too many requests are open concurrently on  your postgres DB? It looks like the limit is 10. Also, is it possible it's timing out? Are any queries taking an unusually long amount of time?

Comment: @AnthonyE too many concurrent requests is not the case. issue is happening with a single user. the query usually takes 30ms, so i doubt that being a problem

Comment: Could be a network issue. What happens if you connect to the database directly using `psql` or a similar postgres client?

Comment: @AnthonyE when this request is in progress. Am able to connect to the database using psql and run queries without any issues.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Does this work only when the request is in progress? Are you not able to reliably connect to the DB outside of Rails?

Comment: @AnthonyE sorry for the confusion. Am able to reliably connect to the DB outside of rails.